# ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller. AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, removechild, addchild

i'm trying to make a space invaders type game with bullets shooting and ships crashing into one another using the hitTestObject function but i can't get the removeChild(); function to work without the Error above. Here's the Code what should i do.

```
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.MovieClip;

var count:int = 1;

//adding the components
var NewBullet:MovieClip = new Bullet;

    var Ship_M:MovieClip = new Ship; 
    Ship_M.x = 270;
    Ship_M.y = 470;
    addChild(Ship_M);


    var Ship_E:MovieClip = new E_Ship;
    Ship_E.x = 270;
    Ship_E.y = 5;
    addChild(Ship_E);


stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME , Rec);
function Rec(e:Event):void{
  if (NewBullet.hitTestObject(Ship_E))
  {
    removeChild(Ship_E);
    removeChild(NewBullet);

  }

   if (Ship_E.hitTestObject(Ship_M))
   {
      removeChild(Ship_E);
      removeChild(Ship_M);
    }



    }

function Moves(e:Event):void{

            NewBullet.y -= 30;

    if (NewBullet.y < 0 )
        {

         removeChild(NewBullet);

          count++;
    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, Moves);

        }

          trace (count);
    }



//For Moving the Spaceship          
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, Move);

function Move (event:KeyboardEvent):void{

 switch(event.keyCode)

    {
        case 37: 
            if (Ship_M.hitTestObject(Stop_L1))
            {
                Ship_M.x -=  0;
            }
            else
            {
                Ship_M.x -=  10;
            }
        break;

        case 38:
            if (Ship_M.hitTestObject(Stop_U1))
            {
                Ship_M.x -=  0;
            }
            else
            {
                Ship_M.y -=  10;
            }

        break;

        case 39:
            if (Ship_M.hitTestObject(Stop_R1))
            {
                Ship_M.x -=  0;
            }
            else
            {
                Ship_M.x +=  10;
            }

        break;

        case 40:
            if (Ship_M.hitTestObject(Stop_D1))
            {
                Ship_M.x -=  0;
            }
            else
            {
                Ship_M.y +=  10;
            }

        break;


        case 32:
        addChild(NewBullet);
        NewBullet.x = Ship_M.x;
        NewBullet.y = Ship_M.y;

        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, Moves);
        break;

        default:

    }

}
```

Comment: Ideally you should name your variables with lowerCamelCase to avoid confusion. Class names typically begin with a capital letter.

Comment: Please consider using raster (bitmapData) and copyPixels to 'render' your game for greatly improved performance.

Answer (score 1):

Replace yours

```
removeChild(SomeSprite);
```

with

```
if (SomeSprite.parent)
    SomeSprite.parent.removeChild(SomeSprite);
```

An objects parent can only call removeChild.

Comment: Thanks, Can you help me make multiple bullets

Comment: Can you describe your problem with bullets?

Answer (score 1):

You may not need this in your particular circumstance, but I have a helper function to remove a child and make it eligible for GC which goes like so:

```
private function remove(child:DisplayObject):void
{
    if(child && child.parent)
    {
        child.parent.removeChild(child);
        child = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you do removeChild(NewBullet) twice, first when it hits Ship_E and second when it leaves boundary. A simple solution will be whenever your NewBullet is removed from stage, set it a flag, say "enabled" which would mean the bullet can trigger events, and check it throughout your code whenever you have to check for the bullet.

Note, you have only one bullet, is it normal?

Comment: Well, it's not so easy. You need an Array that will hold all your bullets, and you will have to check each and every one out of there if they are in bounds and if they hit your enemies (of course, each enemy vs each bullet), and another Array for enemy bullets. All this is checked within a single ENTER_FRAME listener that never gets removed, instead you remove a bullet out of that array, and remove it from display as well, and literally forget it. Reuse technique is better than this, but you first have to learn to walk before you can fly.

Comment: I'm actually pretty good at flying in Java and C++ i just don't understand the logic to use not the code, but anyways what you're saying is i should a for statement to fill and array with bullets fire them and re immerse right ??

Comment: Not just fire, but track throughout their lifespan. But yes, something like that.

Comment: Dude thanks for your responses but please help me one more time. I've been watching alot of tutorials and i can't figure out why mine shoot only the same bullets how did you see that and what can i do, do you want the updated code ?

Comment: That's a pretty complex problem, but first, you need to remove `NewBullet` and replace it with an array of bullets, then make your player shoot more than one bullet with different angles and then make all of them fly. A hint: what you are doing with one bullet, should be done with each active bullet, but do not use listeners on bullets - they are too slow and you risk getting memory leaks.